# Problem signing into Apple ID

Tags: icloud

I can't sign into iCloud because the account is set up under my OLD email address and I don't remember the password. How can I change the iCloud account to new email address so that it is useable?

I am using an iPhone 5s with iOS 9.2.

Comment: Start at https://iforgot.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have Find My iPhone enabled:
On your iPhone, go to Settings > iCloud and tap Sign Out on the bottom. Then just sign back in with your new email address.

If you do:
Go to the link below and use it to reset the password for the *old* email.

You can manage your Apple ID at [appleid.apple.com](https://appleid.apple.com).

Comment: I have an apple ID that I can access but it is connected to my newer email address.  icloud is connected to OLD email address with no memory of password

Comment: @Lulu Okay, I've edited my answer.

Comment: The phone will still be activation-locked to the original ID. You will, at some point, have to remember the password.

Comment: @Tetsujin Right, but only if the OP has Find My iPhone enabled. If that's the case, he'll have to go to the link I provided and reset the password for the old email adress. I'll edit my answer.